# FME shapefile writer NULL values in date format fields

Tags: shapefile, fme-form, date, null

I have a data source with string fields containing dates formatted like `20180202120000 (YYYYMMDDhhmmss)` and I would like to write these in date fields in a shapefile using FME (2016.1).

**UPDATE**: Feature Type Properties for [ESRISHAPE] writer:

[image]

In order to get the required ISO date format `YYYY-MM-DD` I've set a `DateFormatter` transformer like shown below:

[image]

When I redirect the writer to FMEInspector, the result looks as expected, but in the resulting shapefile the date fields contains only `NULL` values.

No Idea what I'm doing wrong, any hints?

Comment: dBase-Iii+ doesn't allow you to choose date format.

Comment: Well the FME esrishape writer does, as can be seen in my updated answer.

Comment: No, I mean you *have to* use YYYYMMDD to store the data. You can chosse invalid formats, or you chosse the only supported one and have it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Meanwhile I found an answer to this issue myself. There is an entry in the FME Knowledge Center concerning the problem:

https://knowledge.safe.com/questions/46033/date-is-shown-in-inspector-but-not-coming-up-in-sh.html

Bottom line is that *Destination Date Format* must be set to **FME Date (%Y%m%d)**, then everthing works fine:

[image]